# Puppeteer Problem with writing to pdf of certain tab

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

i have a really hideous problem with puppeteer in headless mode.

I open a page, simulate a button click on the page(print), which opens the specific print orientated page for the first page and i want to write that print version to pdf.

I tested the whole thing in headless mode: false to see whats going on and it seems to work fine. First Page is opened, Button click is triggered, new Tab with the Page i want is opened.

But the Problem is...when i want to write to PDF it always uses the first page.

Would greatly appreciate a solution for this since its driving me nuts.

Some of the Code.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
var response = await page.goto(formUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
await page.waitForSelector('button[name="Print"]');
await page.click('button[name="Print"]');
const pagewnew = await browser.pages();
await pagenew[2].bringToFront();
```

Edit: Added PDF print code

```
await page.pdf({
      path: outputFile,
      format: 'A4',
      landscape: true,
      displayHeaderFooter: false,
      printBackground: false,    
      margin: {
        top: '10mm',
        right: '10mm',
        bottom: '10mm',
        left: '10mm',
      },
    });
```

Comment: Can you also include the code that you are using to print the pdf?

Comment: I added the code for the pdf. Nothing special tbh

Comment: `await pagenew[2].pdf { ...}`  ???

Comment: As @Rippo mentioned, instead of `page.pdf`, you need to call `pagenew[2].pdf` because `page` refers to the original tab you opened using `browser.newPage`